# Using Javascript to select nested element

Tags: javascript

How can I select a nested element

For example

We have a something like this (this is what Page list looks like when searching for people on **linkedin**)

```
<li class="page-list">
      <ol>
            <li class="active">1</li>
            <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6289="6289" data-is-animating-click="true">2</button></li>
            <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6291="6291">3</button></li>
            <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6293="6293">4</button></li>
            <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6295="6295">5</button></li>
            <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6297="6297">6</button></li>
            <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6299="6299">7</button></li>
            <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6301="6301">8</button></li>
            <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6303="6303">9</button></li>
            <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6305="6305">10</button></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
```

Now, just like this there are multiple li elements on the page but only one element with `<li class="page-list">`

Now, From this li I want to click/select this

```
<button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6291="6291">3</button>
```

which is further nested under `<li>`

**[Question]** Can someone please help me and tell how can i select/click on this? Also I can't use `data-ember-action` because in data-ember-action-6289, 6289 is not fixed and random (different for different searches probably) and hence when I create a script to perform the action, It won't know about number in data-ember-action.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `querySelector` would do it:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('[data-ember-action-6291="6291"]'))
```

```html
<li class="page-list">
  <ol>
    <li class="active">1</li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6289="6289" data-is-animating-click="true">2</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6291="6291">3</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6293="6293">4</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6295="6295">5</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6297="6297">6</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6299="6299">7</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6301="6301">8</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6303="6303">9</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6305="6305">10</button></li>
  </ol>
</li>
```

If you can't count on the `data-` attributes, then just select the third child of the `ol`:

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector('.page-list li:nth-child(3)')
);
```

```html
<li class="page-list">
  <ol>
    <li class="active">1</li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6289="6289" data-is-animating-click="true">2</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6291="6291">3</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6293="6293">4</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6295="6295">5</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6297="6297">6</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6299="6299">7</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6301="6301">8</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6303="6303">9</button></li>
    <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6305="6305">10</button></li>
  </ol>
</li>
```

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: If the `-action#`s are not unique or can't be relied on, how are you trying to distinguish the element you want to select from the rest? You could just select the third element in the `ol`, I guess?

Comment: If i got your question correctly, One way to distinguish it could be the number/value/text between button tag i.e `<button something> 1 </button> <button something> 2 </button>` is different for every button inside `<li class="page-list">` . The other way could be selecting nth button which is inside `<li class="page-list">` . In very simpler terms I know that ***inside page list li** there would be an **ol** and the second li inside that would be the **second page** having **value 2** which I want to **click**